# Why my code won't run when I'm using def?

Tags: python

So, I started python 2 weeks ago.
Something important bugs me, what I just don't understand.

When I have functions why my code stop running? Without `def`s it's working.
In my example I can't call just `kezdo()`, because i get an empty console.

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Anyone can explain it with my example code?

```py
def kerdes(self):
    self.open1 = self.open("kerdesek.txt")
    self.open2 = self.open1.read()
    print(self.open2)
    return kezdo(self)

def kezdo(self):
    print(self.open2)
    user = int(input("valasz egy kerdest: "))
    kerdesek = self.open2

    valaszok = ("egyvalasz", "ketvalasz")
    kv = {kerdesek[user]: valaszok[user]}

    print(kv)
```

if I add kezdo()
then I get an error:

```
Error: kezdo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you are using OOP, can you provide more information about your entire class?

Comment: If you are getting nothing in the console then you may not be calling any methods (as far as you've shown us you aren't). I suggest you create an instance of your class then call the methods and print that.

Comment: this is the whole code. I just wanted to show an example.  If I delete kerdes, kezdo functions then my example code working. I get my input in console. but when when I'm using these 2 fuctions, then my console is empty.

Comment: What's this code supposed to do? It doesn't really make sense. You're using `self`, which is the conventional parameter name for a class instance, but you're not using classes? Then why did you add `self`? Please make a [mre] including minimal code --preferably in English so we can understand the intention -- and your expected output. It'd also help to include any example input, i.e. the contents of `kerdesek.txt`, if relevant. If you want more tips, see [ask].

Comment: When you say it works properly without the functions, what do you mean exactly? What does that code look like? I think you think `self` is required for functions, which is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

you should call the functions. like this:

```
kerdes()
kezdo()
```

Comment: yes, thats what I tried. but in this case, i get an error:  TypeError: kezdo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Answer (score -1):

I can only take a guess based on the limited information but it appears as if you are defining these methods (`kezdo()` and `kerdes()`) in some class.

In that case, you need to use `self` when calling these methods, or Python won't know what you mean.

It needs to be something along the lines of:

```py
def kerdes(self):
    self.open1 = self.open("kerdesek.txt")
    self.open2 = self.open1.read()
    print(self.open2)
    return self.kezdo(self)
    #      ^^^^
    #      You need to use self here.
```

Comment: OP updated and this is no longer helpful. We recommend avoiding guessing for exactly this reason. Instead, wait until OP clarifies the problem before posting an answer.

Comment: That said, the problem is still not totally clear, argh. I don't know why OP added `self` if they're not using classes.